# Cannot add a new package on julia

Tags: git, dataframe, julia

I'm trying to add a new package on Julia. The name of the package is [DataFrames.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl). To add this package, I've run the julia, and simply type `Pkg.add("DataFrames")`. Unfortunately, when I do that, I got the following errors:

```
julia> Pkg.add("DataFrames")
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
ERROR: failed process: Process(`git --work-tree=~/theuserxxx/.julia/v0.4/METADATA --git-dir=~/theuserxxx/.julia/v0.4/METADATA/.git update-index -q --really-refresh`, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
 in run at ./process.jl:531
 in success at pkg/git.jl:30
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:54
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:73
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd at file.jl:22
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:31
 in add at pkg.jl:23
```

Morever, whenever I tried to update a existing package, I also get the same errors:

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
ERROR: failed process: Process(`git pull --rebase -q`, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
 in pipeline_error at process.jl:555
 in run at process.jl:531
 in anonymous at pkg/entry.jl:283
 in withenv at env.jl:160
 in anonymous at pkg/entry.jl:282
 in cd at ./file.jl:22
 in update at ./pkg/entry.jl:272
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd at file.jl:22
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:31
 in update at ./pkg.jl:45
```

Is there anyone who can help me to solve this problem? Currently, I'm using `julia 0.4.5` but this problem started before I moved to 0.4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As silly as it may sound, your best bet is probably to delete your METADATA folder, then re-run the `Pkg.add("DataFrames")` command. Of course, this will delete all the packages you've previously downloaded, so you'll have to reinstall.

Obviously, don't wipe out your directory if you have unregistered packages in it that aren't on backed up on GitHub. But often when you get errors like these, it's because the METADATA repo on your local computer got messed up somehow.